# Update value of LiveData everytime one of other LiveData updates its value

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have a `LiveData` which contains a List like so:

```
val originalSourceLiveaData = MutableLiveData<List<SomeType>>()
```

Now I have another `LiveData` which should indicate the filtering of the `originalSourceLiveaData`'s value.

```
val filterLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
```

What I want is that everytime either one of those `LiveData` change value, a resulting list should be updated. I tried doing something like this:

```
val filteredListLiveData = MediatorLiveData<List<SomeType>().apply {
    addSource(originalSourceLiveaData) { this.value = filteringMethod() }
    addSource(filterLiveData) { this.value = filteringMethod() }
}
```

This works just fine but I wonder whether there is a better solution to this.

My issue is that if another LiveData is added I would have to add it as source like so:

```
val filteredListLiveData = MediatorLiveData<List<SomeType>().apply {
    addSource(originalSourceLiveaData) { this.value = filteringMethod() }
    addSource(filterLiveData) { this.value = filteringMethod() }
    addSource(anotherSourceLiveData) { 
        this.value = filteringMethod() // this feels like a duplicate 
    }
}
```

Any ideas on improving this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does filteringMethod do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it more reactive-style using the extension function feature of Kotlin.

Assume that you have `firstLiveaData` and `secondLiveData` with the same type of `T`. Now you want to filter them first and then listen to all of their changes.

So, you can add the following extension functions:

- `filter` function will filter your livedata based on the given predicate function
- `addSources` function will do the boilerplate of adding multiple livedata and listen to their changes

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.filter(predicate : (T) -> Boolean): LiveData<T> {
    val mutableLiveData = MediatorLiveData<T>()
    mutableLiveData.addSource(this) {
        if(predicate(it))
            mutableLiveData.value = it
    }
    return mutableLiveData
}

fun <T> MediatorLiveData<T>.addSources(vararg listOfLiveData: LiveData<T>, callback: (T) -> Unit) {
    listOfLiveData.forEach {
        addSource(it, callback)
    }
}
```

Also, you can merge multiple `LivaData` objects with the same type into one with `merge` function:

```
fun <T> merge(vararg liveDataList: LiveData<T>): LiveData<T> {
    val mergedLiveData = MediatorLiveData<T>()
    liveDataList.forEach { liveData ->

        liveData.value?.let {
            mergedLiveData.value = it
        }

        mergedLiveData.addSource(liveData) { source ->
            mergedLiveData.value = source
        }
    }
    return mergedLiveData
}
```

Here is an example:

```
fun doSomething() {
    val firstLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<SomeType>>()
    val secondLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<SomeType>>()

    merge(firstLiveData, secondLiveData).filter { someFilterFunction() }.observe(...)
}
```

If you have a different type of `LiveData` (e.g. `firstLiveData<Int>` and `secondLiveData<String>`), you can simply add a `map` extension function.

Comment: well yeah this might be nicer but still... `firstLiveData.filter { filterMethod() },
        secondLiveData.filter { filterMethod() }` seems to be a repeat. Is there no other solution for that?

Comment: I think that's better. I think ill select your answer now since it satisfies the question.